# SIGILL with code 2 when C++ method returns on SLES11

Tags: c++, suse

In one of my test program I have method call that returns `String` object.

```
xms::String propVal =  connFact->getStringProperty("PROP_NAME");
```

`xms::String` is a class representing a string.

When my test code runs on SUSE Linux 11, I get a SIGILL with code 2 immediately after `getStringProperty` method returns and before assigning the return value to `propVal`. Ideally the copy constructor of `xms::String` should have been called but I get a SIGILL.

What could be the reason? This happens only on SUES Linux 11, not on other OS like Windows or AIX or RHEL.

Comment: Have you debugged into the code to see what's triggering the signal? What's getStringProperty returning?

Comment: Not debugged (not so skilled in Linux). getStringProperty returns a String.

Comment: I'd recommend you look at this under the debugger so you know where the signal emanates from. You might also want to look at the value you get back from getStringProperty.

Comment: Did you compile the program on one system and try to run it on a different one? If so, there's several possibilities - e.g. the system it was compiled on allows instructions that don't exist on the one you're running it on, bad interactions with different versions of libraries that what it was compiled with, actual bugs that only get exposed in specific situations, etc...